# Possible to wait until first frame is drawn before showing OpenGLES UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es

My game has two views: a UIKit menu screen and the EAGLView (UIView with a CAEAGLLayer backing store).  No matter what I try, whenever the EAGLView comes back into view it flashes the contents of the previous frame for just a split second.

Does it have something to do with switching contexts between my UIView menu and my EAGLView game?  I've seen other notes about destroying and recreating contexts when an EAGLView willAppear but that doesn't work for me.

I'm using OpenGLES1.1 by the way.

**EDIT:**

On further thought what I want to do is this:  wait until the first frame is draw before showing the EAGLView.  Otherwise, and old frame is displayed when the EAGLView appears.  I can't seem to do this, however, no matter how early in the lifecycle I try.  It's almost like there's some latency in step two of this chain wherein I see the previous contents:

UIView dismisses itself -1-> EAGLView becomes visible -2-> Able to draw into EAGLView

Comment: What is an EAGLView, a UIView with a CAEAGLLayer backing store? It would be helpful to show some code for the transition between the views, and some of your rendering loop.

Comment: Does this issue still occur with a GLKView?